# Mule ESB Any point Studio- Show error when web service is down or timeout

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, mule-el, mule-esb

I have consumed a wsdl service which is working fine and if you change any request it will give you 500 error now what i need to display a predefined message if the web service that i am consuming is down & also for timeout.

Also one thing some of web service calling is not working from web service consumer no idea why but they are working from CXF any idea?

Answer (score 0):

To catch a timeout from a WS, use a Catch Exception Strategy and make it execute when the following condition is met: `exception.causedBy(java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException)`

To catch SOAP faults:
`exception.causedBy(org.mule.module.SoapFaultException)`
and
`exception.causedBy(org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault)`

That should get you started. Not sure about the second part as to why you can't always use the WS Consumer component.